Using FindRoot inside Table
I want to use FindRoot inside Table to get solutions from several guesses.  For one- variable non-linear equations this works well:
Table[FindRoot[Sin[x/5]==Cos[Log[x+1]]+3/4,{x,k}],{k,{-8/9,-1/2,4,14,30,46,65,79,106,125,136}}]

However, for two-variable equations it does not work.  My 1st. attempt:
Table[FindRoot[{Sin[x]==y,Tan[Log[x]]==y},{{x,m},{y,n}}],{{m,{2,10,12,15,19,22,25,28,31,34,38,41,44,47}},{n,{1,-1,-0.9,-0.5, -0.2, 0, 0.1,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}}]


My 2nd. attempt:
Table[FindRoot[{Sin[x]==y,Tan[Log[x]]==y},{{x,m},{y,n}}],{m,{2,10,12,15,19,22,25,28,31,34,38,41,44,47},n,{1,-1,-0.9,-0.5, -0.2, 0, 0.1,0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}]


¿Can this approach be used to provide guesses to the system of equations, any other method?
Thanks in advance.

It's simple syntax mistake: Table[FindRoot[{Sin[x] == y, Tan[Log[x]] == y}, {{x, m}, {y, n}}], {m, {2, 10, 12,     15, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 38, 41, 44, 47}}, {n, {1, -1, -0.9, -0.5, -0.2, 0,     0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}] Please read the document of Table carefully.

@xzczd, thanks, your code works but it prints each solution 14 times.  Following your advice I read the Table document and I think that this particular syntax is better suited for creating matrices: "Table[expr,spec1,spec2] is effectively equivalent to Table[Table[expr,spec2],spec1]."  Thanks again.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"];

Map FindRoot onto the initial estimates
sol = FindRoot[{Sin[x] == y, 
     Tan[Log[x]] == y}, {{x, #[[1]]}, {y, #[[2]]}}] & /@
  Transpose[{{2, 10, 12, 15, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 38, 41, 44, 47},
    {1, -1, -0.9, -0.5, -0.2, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}]

(* {{x -> 2.06063, y -> 0.882411}, {x -> 10.7343, y -> -0.966074}, {x -> 11.5917,
   y -> -0.827534}, {x -> 16.0975, y -> -0.379751}, {x -> 18.6273, 
  y -> -0.220434}, {x -> 22.0399, y -> -0.0487749}, {x -> 25.2191, 
  y -> 0.0862205}, {x -> 28.0772, y -> 0.195814}, {x -> 31.7493, 
  y -> 0.327265}, {x -> 34.1355, y -> 0.409589}, {x -> 38.2823, 
  y -> 0.55072}, {x -> 40.1777, y -> 0.615474}, {x -> 44.8767, 
  y -> 0.779839}, {x -> 46.1521, y -> 0.825923}} *)

Show[
 ContourPlot[{Sin[x] == y, Tan[Log[x]] == y},
  {x, 0, 50}, {y, -1, 1},
  PlotPoints -> 25,
  MaxRecursion -> 2],
 Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[5],
   Tooltip[Point[{x, y}], NumberForm[{x, y}, {5, 3}]] /. sol}]]


